# ¿Cómo obtengo el nombre de usuario de un usuario en Windows?

Tags: c++, windows

Estoy creando un programa donde el usuario se puede registrar, los datos se guardan en un fichero de texto en una ubicación especifica del disco duro. Luego tengo que acceder a ese fichero para obtener los datos.

Este código funciona bien, pero solo en mi ordenador.

```
bool registro(string correo, string password, string username){
    ofstream archivo;
    archivo.open("C:\\Users\\edgar\\FCMDUSERS.txt", ios::app);
    if(archivo.fail()) return false; // Para saber desde la función main si ocurrió un error

    archivo<<correo<<"|"<<password<<"|"<<username<<endl;
    archivo.close();
    return true; // Para saber desde la función main si todo salió bien
}
```

Necesito el nombre de usuario del equipo para así guardar el fichero en la ubicación (C:\Users\Usuario\FCMDUSERS.txt) ¿Existe alguna función para obtener el nombre de usuario el windows? ¿Cómo hago tal cosa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que necesitas no es el nombre del usuario, sino **su directorio asignado**..

Para ello, puedes usar la función [`SHGetFolderPathA( )`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetfolderpatha)

```
#include <Shlobj.h>  // Necesario.

...

char path[MAX_PATH];

SHGetFolderPathA( nullptr, CSIDL_PROFILE, nullptr, 0, path );
```